# Multilanguage convention to invoke debugger?

Tags: debuggers

Are there hopes that various programming languages will establish a convention where using .debug() leads to the same result instead of using breakpoint() in python3, debug() in javascript testcafe , debugger() javascript chrome ?

The idea could apply to all programming languages that cames with a builtin  [debugger](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger)  functionalities.

In the specific case I'm facing a project with frontend in html and javascript and backend in python, so multiple languages are involved at same time and my memory is not very good at handling many words to do the same thing.

Comment: Standardization of naming across languages is far from being solved, even for very similar parts of standard libraries. Personally I often hope that someday some community-driven website will make an inventory of the variations in all the names and analyze their pros and cons, and become the tool of choice for implementers to get (automated?) recommended naming suggestions. I'm not expecting it to happen this decade, though.

Comment: I don't think there would be a huge benefit in standardizing the syntax for triggering the debugger, you need knowledge of the language to do anything with the results anyways

Comment: Plus, a lot of languages require specific libraries for debugging, rather than having a large amount of inbuilt debuggers. So, to implement such a solution with minimal benefit, one would have to convince not only the language designers but library designers as well.

Comment: It's not clear what "leads to the same result" could mean, when you are talking about various different languages with different semantics.

Comment: How would you use `.debug()` in a language in the Lisp family? They don't even use `name()` as the syntax for calling functions. And what about Prolog? It doesn't really make sense to standardize at this level when syntaxes are so different. At best you could specify this for languages that model their syntax after C.

Comment: In my experience, activating a debugger with *any* kind of syntax is rare, compared to specifying a breakpoint without touching the source code. In that situation, the language has even less to do with how the user sees it - it's about the UI design of IDEs or standalone debugger front-ends.